# Search area get coordinates in swift MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, clgeocoder

How can I get the coordinates of of an area and set it to the focus of the mapview in swift?

I have this code:

```
var address = "1 Steve Street, Johannesburg, South Africa"
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))
}
})
```

But that plots a point from an address, how can I get just an area, ie: `Johannesburg` and set it to be the main area of focus on the map view?

Comment: needed this code to convert from address to lat/long - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placemark has a `region` property of type `CLCircularRegion` (a subclass of `CLRegion`) which gives its center coordinate and radius in meters.

Using that with `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`, you can create an `MKCoordinateRegion` to set the map view's `region`.

Example:

```
var address = "Johannesburg, South Africa"
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {

        if let pmCircularRegion = placemark.region as? CLCircularRegion {

            let metersAcross = pmCircularRegion.radius * 2

            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance
                  (pmCircularRegion.center, metersAcross, metersAcross)

            self.mapView.region = region
        }

    }
})
```